# Firebase Crashlytics falsely reporting crashes?

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics

I have an iPhone app where I use Firebase Crashlytics.

The following happened:

I build a new version of my app and uploaded it to Testflight.
After that I stopped working for the day :)

The next day I saw a crash report in crashlytics for this new app version, dating to approx. 15 min after my upload the previous day. The data says the crash was recorded on an iPhone 7.

So at this point, this specific app version was only available to me and Apple.
I am sure, that I did not open the app (or experienced a crash) at this time AND **I do not even own an iPhone 7**.

I highly doubt that Apple Beta-Reviewers are using an iPhone 7 to review an app, after all it's 2021. Also a review 15 min after upload seems not very likely.

Does anyone have an explanation for this? Is the crash even real?
Is it possible that crashes are falsely reported to/by Crashlytics? If so, how?
I've never heard of such a thing tbh.

Answer (score 2):

No, Crashlytics can’t generate crash reports when no one has run the app. *Someone* ran it.

The fact that you just uploaded it for review makes it very likely that Apple did run it. We have a collection of old devices with various iOS versions for testing our apps in real world scenarios, on less capable devices. I would not be at all surprised if Apple does the same thing.